# Constructing a sequence following some properties

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is there a numberical sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ following these properties:

i) $x_n \in \left[a;b \right)$

ii) $\lim_{n \to \infty }x_n=b$

If the answer is **YES**, point out a sequence.

Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Hmmm I have think about this question but I don't have any idea  @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: I hope the answer is yes. Since this is a small question that I have questioned myself while I do my exercise. @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: $b-\frac{1}{n}$ will converge to $b$

Comment: How about $x_n=\arctan n$?

Comment: @Vasili but how about $x_n>a$? Is it sure that $x_n>a$? I think it must be more strict.

Comment: @TrầnNguyênKhang: I leave it up to you to figure this part. The idea is to find $f(n)$ such as $b-f(n)\ge a$

Comment: the answer is yes, but give it a little more thought, edit your solution to include your attempt and we can verify your attempt.

Comment: @Vasili
Thanks for your idea, I can choose $f\left( n \right)=b-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}-n},\forall a< b$. I construct it by this way:

$b-f\left( n \right)\ge a \Leftrightarrow f\left( n \right)\le b-a$.

Choose $f\left( n \right)=b-\frac{1}{kn}$, so that $\frac{1}{kn}\ge a$. If $a>0$, give us $k\le \frac{1}{an}$, then choose $k=\frac{1}{an}-1$. Thus, $f\left( n \right)=b-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}-n}$. 

If $a<0$, we construct an $f(n)$ in the same way.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh is it clear right now?

Comment: @TrầnNguyênKhang: you can simply take $f(n)=\frac{b-a}{n}$

Comment: Wow, amazing :D

Comment: Thanks everyone very much